# Can't insert or update record to database jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

I am creating a form that is used to insert, update and delete data in a database, managed to do everything right but update and insert are not functioning. Delete works fine. Any help with solution will be 
highly appreciated

FirstController

```
    package com.firstmohform.controller;

    import com.firstmohform.dao.FirstDAO;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import com.firstmohform.model.First;

    @WebServlet(name = "FirstController", urlPatterns = {"/FirstController"})
    public class FirstController extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static String insert_or_edit = "/first.jsp";
private static String list_first = "/listfirst.jsp";
private FirstDAO firstdao;

public FirstController() {
    super();
    firstdao = new FirstDAO();
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String forward = "";
    String action = request.getParameter("action");
    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")) {
        // the other page is sending the survey id, so we can get here and
        // call the remove method
        int survey_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("survey_id"));
        // we remove the survey from the database
        firstdao.removeFirst(survey_id);
        // set the forward string to list and put all surveys in request
        // attribute so we can use them inside the other page
        forward = list_first;
        request.setAttribute("firsts", firstdao.getFirst());
    } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("edit")) {

        forward = insert_or_edit;
        int survey_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("survey_id"));
        First first = firstdao.getFirstById(survey_id);
        request.setAttribute("first", first);

    } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("listFirst")) {
        forward = list_first;
        request.setAttribute("firsts", firstdao.getFirst());
    } else {
        forward = insert_or_edit;
    }
    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
    view.forward(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    First first = new First();
    first.setuname(request.getParameter("uname"));
    first.setp1q1(request.getParameter("p1q1"));
    first.setp1q2(request.getParameter("p1q2"));
    first.setp1q3(request.getParameter("p1q3"));
    first.setp1q4(request.getParameter("p1q4"));
    first.setp1q5(request.getParameter("p1q5"));
    first.setp1q6(request.getParameter("p1q6"));
    first.setp1q7(request.getParameter("p1q7"));
    first.setp1q8(request.getParameter("p1q8"));
    first.setp2q1(request.getParameter("p2q1"));
    first.setp2q2(request.getParameter("p2q2"));
    first.setp2q3(request.getParameter("p2q3"));
    first.setp2q4(request.getParameter("p2q4"));
    first.setp2q5(request.getParameter("p2q5"));
    first.setp2q6(request.getParameter("p2q6"));
    first.setp2q7(request.getParameter("p2q7"));
    first.setp2q8(request.getParameter("p2q8"));
    first.setp2q9(request.getParameter("p2q9"));
    first.setp2q10(request.getParameter("p2q10"));
    first.setp2q11(request.getParameter("p2q11"));
    first.setp2q12(request.getParameter("p2q12"));
    first.setp2q13(request.getParameter("p2q13"));
    first.setp2q14(request.getParameter("p2q14"));
    first.setp2q15(request.getParameter("p2q15"));
    first.setp3q1(request.getParameter("p3q1"));
    first.setp3q2(request.getParameter("p3q2"));
    first.setp3q3(request.getParameter("p3q3"));
    first.setp3q4(request.getParameter("p3q4"));
    first.setp3q5(request.getParameter("p3q5"));
    first.setp3q6(request.getParameter("p3q6"));
    first.setp3q7(request.getParameter("p3q7"));
    first.setp3q8(request.getParameter("p3q8"));
    first.setp3q9(request.getParameter("p3q9"));
    first.setp3q10(request.getParameter("p3q10"));
    first.setp4q1(request.getParameter("p4q1"));
    first.setp4q2(request.getParameter("p4q2"));
    first.setp5q1(request.getParameter("p5q1"));
    first.setp5q2(request.getParameter("p5q2"));
    first.setp5q3(request.getParameter("p5q3"));
    first.setp5q4(request.getParameter("p5q4"));
    first.setp5q5(request.getParameter("p5q5"));
    first.setp6q1(request.getParameter("p6q1"));
    first.setp6q2(request.getParameter("p6q2"));
    first.setp6q3(request.getParameter("p6q3"));
    first.setp6q4(request.getParameter("p6q4"));
    first.setp7q1(request.getParameter("p1q1"));
    first.setp7q2(request.getParameter("p7q2"));
    first.setp7q3(request.getParameter("p7q3"));
    first.setp7q4(request.getParameter("p7q4"));
    first.setp7q5(request.getParameter("p7q5"));
    first.setp8q1(request.getParameter("p8q1"));
    first.setp8q2(request.getParameter("p8q2"));
    first.setp8q3(request.getParameter("p8q3"));
    first.setp8q4(request.getParameter("p8q4"));
    first.setp9q1(request.getParameter("p9q1"));
    first.setp9q2(request.getParameter("p9q2"));
    first.setp9q3(request.getParameter("p9q3"));
    first.setp9q4(request.getParameter("p9q4"));
    first.setp9q5(request.getParameter("p9q5"));
    first.setp9q6(request.getParameter("p9q6"));
    first.setp9q7(request.getParameter("p9q7"));
    first.setp9q8(request.getParameter("p9q8"));
    first.setp10q1(request.getParameter("p10q1"));
    first.setp10q2(request.getParameter("p10q2"));
    first.setp10q3(request.getParameter("p10q3"));
    first.setp10q4(request.getParameter("p10q4"));
    first.setp11q1(request.getParameter("p11q1"));
    first.setp11q2(request.getParameter("p11q2"));
    first.setp11q3(request.getParameter("p11q3"));
    first.setp11q4(request.getParameter("p11q4"));
    first.setp11q5(request.getParameter("p11q5"));
    first.setp11q6(request.getParameter("p11q6"));
    first.setp11q7(request.getParameter("p11q7"));
    first.setp12q1(request.getParameter("p12q1"));
    first.setp12q2(request.getParameter("p12q2"));
    first.setp12q3(request.getParameter("p12q3"));
    first.setp12q4(request.getParameter("p12q4"));
    first.setp12q5(request.getParameter("p12q5"));
    first.setp12q6(request.getParameter("p12q6"));
    first.setp13q1(request.getParameter("p13q1"));
    first.setp13q2(request.getParameter("p13q2"));
    first.setp13q3(request.getParameter("p13q3"));
    first.setp13q4(request.getParameter("p13q4"));
    first.setp13q5(request.getParameter("p13q5"));
    first.setp13q6(request.getParameter("p13q6"));
    first.setp14q1(request.getParameter("p14q1"));
    first.setp14q2(request.getParameter("p14q2"));
    first.setp14q3(request.getParameter("p14q3"));
    first.setp14q4(request.getParameter("p14q4"));
    first.setp14q5(request.getParameter("p14q5"));
    first.setp14q6(request.getParameter("p14q6"));
    first.setp14q7(request.getParameter("p14q7"));
    first.setp14q8(request.getParameter("p14q8"));
    first.setp15q1(request.getParameter("p15q1"));
    first.setp15q2(request.getParameter("p15q2"));
    first.setp15q3(request.getParameter("p15q3"));
    first.setp15q4(request.getParameter("p15q4"));
    first.setp15q5(request.getParameter("p15q5"));
    first.setp15q6(request.getParameter("p15q6"));
    first.setp16q1(request.getParameter("p16q1"));
    first.setp16q2(request.getParameter("p16q2"));
    first.setp16q3(request.getParameter("p16q3"));
    first.setp16q4(request.getParameter("p16q4"));
    first.setp16q5(request.getParameter("p16q5"));
    first.setp16q6(request.getParameter("p16q6"));
    first.setp17q1(request.getParameter("p17q1"));
    first.setp17q2(request.getParameter("p17q2"));
    first.setp17q3(request.getParameter("p17q3"));
    first.setp17q4(request.getParameter("p17q4"));
    first.setp17q5(request.getParameter("p17q5"));
    first.setp18q1(request.getParameter("p18q1"));
    first.setp18q2(request.getParameter("p18q2"));
    first.setp18q3(request.getParameter("p18q3"));
    first.setp18q4(request.getParameter("p18q4"));
    first.setp18q5(request.getParameter("p18q5"));
    first.setp19q1(request.getParameter("p19q1"));
    first.setp19q2(request.getParameter("p19q2"));
    first.setp19q3(request.getParameter("p19q3"));
    first.setp19q4(request.getParameter("p19q4"));
    first.setp19q5(request.getParameter("p19q5"));
    first.setp19q6(request.getParameter("p19q6"));
    first.setp20q1(request.getParameter("p20q1"));
    first.setp20q2(request.getParameter("p20q2"));
    first.setp21q1(request.getParameter("p21q1"));
    first.setp21q2(request.getParameter("p21q2"));
    first.setp21q3(request.getParameter("p21q3"));
    first.setp21q4(request.getParameter("p21q4"));
    first.setp22q1(request.getParameter("p22q1"));
    first.setp22q2(request.getParameter("p22q2"));
    first.setp22q3(request.getParameter("p22q3"));
    first.setp22q4(request.getParameter("p22q4"));
    first.setp23q1(request.getParameter("p23q1"));
    first.setp23q2(request.getParameter("p23q2"));
    first.setp23q3(request.getParameter("p23q3"));
    first.setp24q1(request.getParameter("p24q1"));
    first.setp24q2(request.getParameter("p24q2"));
    first.setp24q3(request.getParameter("p24q3"));
    first.setp24q4(request.getParameter("p24q4"));
    first.setp24q5(request.getParameter("p24q5"));
    first.setp24q6(request.getParameter("p24q6"));
    first.setp25q1(request.getParameter("p25q1"));
    first.setp25q2(request.getParameter("p25q2"));
    first.setp25q3(request.getParameter("p25q3"));
    first.setp25q4(request.getParameter("p25q4"));
    first.setp25q5(request.getParameter("p25q5"));
    first.setp25q6(request.getParameter("p25q6"));
    first.setp25q7(request.getParameter("p25q7"));
    first.setp26q1(request.getParameter("p26q1"));
    first.setp26q2(request.getParameter("p26q2"));
    first.setp26q3(request.getParameter("p26q3"));
    first.setp26q4(request.getParameter("p26q4"));
    first.setp26q5(request.getParameter("p26q5"));
    first.setp26q6(request.getParameter("p26q6"));
    first.setp26q7(request.getParameter("p26q7"));
    first.setp27q1(request.getParameter("p27q1"));
    first.setp27q2(request.getParameter("p27q2"));
    first.setp27q3(request.getParameter("p27q3"));
    String survey_id = request.getParameter("survey_id");
     System.out.println("ola");
    System.out.println(survey_id);
    // what i'm trying to mean here is: if the survey id coming from the
    // request is null
    // then, the user is trying to add someone, otherwise, he's trying to
    // update someone
    first.setp1q3(survey_id);
    firstdao.checkFirst(first);
    //    }
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(list_first);
request.setAttribute("firsts", firstdao.getFirst());
view.forward(request, response);
}

    }
```

FirstDAO

```
    package com.firstmohform.dao;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.sql.*;

    import com.firstmohform.model.First;
    import com.firstmohform.util.Database;

    public class FirstDAO {
private Connection connection;

public FirstDAO() {
    connection = Database.getConnection();
}

public void checkFirst(First first) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("select p1q3 from survey_data_27 where p1q8 = ?");
        ps.setString(1, first.getp1q3());
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) // found
        {
            updateFirst(first);
        } else {
            addFirst(first);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error in check() -->" + ex.getMessage());
    } 
}
public void addFirst(First first) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("insert into survey_data_27(uname, password, email, registeredon) values (?, ?, ?, ? )");
        // Parameters start with 1
        preparedStatement.setString(1, first.getuname());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, first.getp1q1());
        preparedStatement.setString(3, first.getp1q2());
        preparedStatement.setString(4, first.getp1q3());
        preparedStatement.setString(5, first.getp1q4());
        preparedStatement.setString(6, first.getp1q5());
        preparedStatement.setString(7, first.getp1q6());
        preparedStatement.setString(8, first.getp1q7());
        preparedStatement.setString(9, first.getp1q8());
        preparedStatement.setString(10, first.getp2q1());
        preparedStatement.setString(11, first.getp2q2());
        preparedStatement.setString(12, first.getp2q3());
        preparedStatement.setString(13, first.getp2q4());
        preparedStatement.setString(14, first.getp2q5());
        preparedStatement.setString(15, first.getp2q6());
        preparedStatement.setString(16, first.getp2q7());
        preparedStatement.setString(17, first.getp2q8());
        preparedStatement.setString(18, first.getp2q9());
        preparedStatement.setString(19, first.getp2q10());
        preparedStatement.setString(20, first.getp2q11());
        preparedStatement.setString(21, first.getp2q12());
        preparedStatement.setString(22, first.getp2q13());
        preparedStatement.setString(23, first.getp2q14());
        preparedStatement.setString(24, first.getp2q15());
        preparedStatement.setString(25, first.getp3q1());
        preparedStatement.setString(26, first.getp3q2());
        preparedStatement.setString(27, first.getp3q3());
        preparedStatement.setString(28, first.getp3q4());
        preparedStatement.setString(29, first.getp3q5());
        preparedStatement.setString(30, first.getp3q6());
        preparedStatement.setString(31, first.getp3q7());
        preparedStatement.setString(32, first.getp3q8());
        preparedStatement.setString(33, first.getp3q9());
        preparedStatement.setString(34, first.getp3q10());
        preparedStatement.setString(35, first.getp4q1());
        preparedStatement.setString(36, first.getp4q2());
        preparedStatement.setString(37, first.getp5q1());
        preparedStatement.setString(38, first.getp5q2());
        preparedStatement.setString(39, first.getp5q3());
        preparedStatement.setString(40, first.getp5q4());
        preparedStatement.setString(41, first.getp5q5());
        preparedStatement.setString(42, first.getp6q1());
        preparedStatement.setString(43, first.getp6q2());
        preparedStatement.setString(44, first.getp6q3());
        preparedStatement.setString(45, first.getp6q4());
        preparedStatement.setString(46, first.getp7q1());
        preparedStatement.setString(47, first.getp7q2());
        preparedStatement.setString(48, first.getp7q3());
        preparedStatement.setString(49, first.getp7q4());
        preparedStatement.setString(50, first.getp7q5());
        preparedStatement.setString(51, first.getp8q1());
        preparedStatement.setString(52, first.getp8q2());
        preparedStatement.setString(53, first.getp8q3());
        preparedStatement.setString(54, first.getp8q4());
        preparedStatement.setString(55, first.getp9q1());
        preparedStatement.setString(56, first.getp9q2());
        preparedStatement.setString(57, first.getp9q3());
        preparedStatement.setString(58, first.getp9q4());
        preparedStatement.setString(59, first.getp9q5());
        preparedStatement.setString(60, first.getp9q6());
        preparedStatement.setString(61, first.getp9q7());
        preparedStatement.setString(62, first.getp9q8());
        preparedStatement.setString(63, first.getp10q1());
        preparedStatement.setString(64, first.getp10q2());
        preparedStatement.setString(65, first.getp10q3());
        preparedStatement.setString(66, first.getp10q4());
        preparedStatement.setString(67, first.getp11q1());
        preparedStatement.setString(68, first.getp11q2());
        preparedStatement.setString(69, first.getp11q3());
        preparedStatement.setString(70, first.getp11q4());
        preparedStatement.setString(71, first.getp11q5());
        preparedStatement.setString(72, first.getp11q6());
        preparedStatement.setString(73, first.getp11q7());
        preparedStatement.setString(74, first.getp12q1());
        preparedStatement.setString(75, first.getp12q2());
        preparedStatement.setString(76, first.getp12q3());
        preparedStatement.setString(77, first.getp12q4());
        preparedStatement.setString(78, first.getp12q5());
        preparedStatement.setString(79, first.getp12q6());
        preparedStatement.setString(80, first.getp13q1());
        preparedStatement.setString(81, first.getp13q2());
        preparedStatement.setString(82, first.getp13q3());
        preparedStatement.setString(83, first.getp13q4());
        preparedStatement.setString(84, first.getp13q5());
        preparedStatement.setString(85, first.getp13q6());
        preparedStatement.setString(86, first.getp14q1());
        preparedStatement.setString(87, first.getp14q2());
        preparedStatement.setString(88, first.getp14q3());
        preparedStatement.setString(89, first.getp14q4());
        preparedStatement.setString(90, first.getp14q5());
        preparedStatement.setString(91, first.getp14q6());
        preparedStatement.setString(92, first.getp14q7());
        preparedStatement.setString(93, first.getp14q8());
        preparedStatement.setString(94, first.getp15q1());
        preparedStatement.setString(95, first.getp15q2());
        preparedStatement.setString(96, first.getp15q3());
        preparedStatement.setString(97, first.getp15q4());
        preparedStatement.setString(98, first.getp15q5());
        preparedStatement.setString(99, first.getp15q6());
        preparedStatement.setString(100, first.getp16q1());
        preparedStatement.setString(101, first.getp16q2());
        preparedStatement.setString(102, first.getp16q3());
        preparedStatement.setString(103, first.getp16q4());
        preparedStatement.setString(104, first.getp16q5());
        preparedStatement.setString(105, first.getp16q6());
        preparedStatement.setString(106, first.getp17q1());
        preparedStatement.setString(107, first.getp17q2());
        preparedStatement.setString(108, first.getp17q3());
        preparedStatement.setString(109, first.getp17q4());
        preparedStatement.setString(110, first.getp17q5());
        preparedStatement.setString(111, first.getp18q1());
        preparedStatement.setString(112, first.getp18q2());
        preparedStatement.setString(113, first.getp18q3());
        preparedStatement.setString(114, first.getp18q4());
        preparedStatement.setString(115, first.getp18q5());
        preparedStatement.setString(116, first.getp19q1());
        preparedStatement.setString(117, first.getp19q2());
        preparedStatement.setString(118, first.getp19q3());
        preparedStatement.setString(119, first.getp19q4());
        preparedStatement.setString(120, first.getp19q5());
        preparedStatement.setString(121, first.getp19q6());
        preparedStatement.setString(122, first.getp20q1());
        preparedStatement.setString(123, first.getp20q2());
        preparedStatement.setString(124, first.getp21q1());
        preparedStatement.setString(125, first.getp21q2());
        preparedStatement.setString(126, first.getp21q3());
        preparedStatement.setString(127, first.getp21q4());
        preparedStatement.setString(128, first.getp22q1());
        preparedStatement.setString(129, first.getp22q2());
        preparedStatement.setString(130, first.getp22q3());
        preparedStatement.setString(131, first.getp22q4());
        preparedStatement.setString(132, first.getp23q1());
        preparedStatement.setString(133, first.getp23q2());
        preparedStatement.setString(134, first.getp23q3());
        preparedStatement.setString(135, first.getp24q1());
        preparedStatement.setString(136, first.getp24q2());
        preparedStatement.setString(137, first.getp24q3());
        preparedStatement.setString(138, first.getp24q4());
        preparedStatement.setString(139, first.getp24q5());
        preparedStatement.setString(140, first.getp24q6());
        preparedStatement.setString(141, first.getp25q1());
        preparedStatement.setString(142, first.getp25q2());
        preparedStatement.setString(143, first.getp25q3());
        preparedStatement.setString(144, first.getp25q4());
        preparedStatement.setString(145, first.getp25q5());
        preparedStatement.setString(146, first.getp25q6());
        preparedStatement.setString(147, first.getp25q7());
        preparedStatement.setString(148, first.getp26q1());
        preparedStatement.setString(149, first.getp26q2());
        preparedStatement.setString(150, first.getp26q3());
        preparedStatement.setString(151, first.getp26q4());
        preparedStatement.setString(152, first.getp26q5());
        preparedStatement.setString(153, first.getp26q6());
        preparedStatement.setString(154, first.getp26q7());
        preparedStatement.setString(155, first.getp27q1());
        preparedStatement.setString(156, first.getp27q2());
        preparedStatement.setString(157, first.getp27q3());
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void removeFirst(int survey_id) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("delete from survey_dat_27 where uname=?");
        // Parameters start with 1
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, survey_id);
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void updateFirst(First first) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("update survey_data_27 set uname=?, p1q1=?, p1q2=?"
                + "where survey_id=?");
        // Parameters start with 1
        preparedStatement.setString(1, first.getuname());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, first.getp1q1());
        preparedStatement.setString(3, first.getp1q2());
        preparedStatement.setString(4, first.getp1q3());
        preparedStatement.setString(5, first.getp1q4());
        preparedStatement.setString(6, first.getp1q5());
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public List<First> getFirst() {
    List<First> firsts = new ArrayList<First>();
    try {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from survey_data_27");
        while (rs.next()) {
            First first = new First();
            first.setuname(rs.getString("uname"));
            first.setp1q1(rs.getString("p1q1"));
            first.setp1q2(rs.getString("p1q2"));
            first.setp1q3(rs.getString("p1q3"));
            firsts.add(first);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return firsts;
}

public First getFirstById(int survey_id) {
    First first = new First();
    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("select * from survey_data_27 where p1q3=?");
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, survey_id);
        ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {
            first.setuname(rs.getString("uname"));
            first.setp1q1(rs.getString("p1q1"));
            first.setp1q2(rs.getString("p1q2"));
            first.setp1q3(rs.getString("p1q3"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return first;
}
    }
```

Comment: "but update and insert are not functioning" is not very detailed. What happens? Nothing? An error message? An exception? A BSOD? A teleportation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem** for the below part

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("update survey_data_27 set uname=?, p1q1=?, p1q2=?"
                + "where survey_id=?");
```

there are total 4 variables but your code is setting 6 variables(below is your code)

```
// Parameters start with 1
preparedStatement.setString(1, first.getuname());
preparedStatement.setString(2, first.getp1q1());
preparedStatement.setString(3, first.getp1q2());
preparedStatement.setString(4, first.getp1q3());
preparedStatement.setString(5, first.getp1q4());
preparedStatement.setString(6, first.getp1q5());
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

**Solution** remove the following 2 lines

```
 preparedStatement.setString(5, first.getp1q4());
        preparedStatement.setString(6, first.getp1q5());
```

**Inserting problem**

As per `PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("insert into survey_data_27(uname, password, email, registeredon) values (?, ?, ?, ? )")`

you have set only 4 variables
but you are setting 157 variables

Comment: Thanks mate,let me try that